# Heroku Hobby server still sleeps or issue with NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, heroku, server

I've noticed that my NodeJS application which resides on a Heroku Hobby server after no activity does a "soft restart". By that I mean it doesn't do big actions like reinitialize the ORM system or recreates the HTTP server, however it does seem to forget callback functions and `global` variables or any variables that were dynamically created and held in memory.

Does Heroku still "sleep" even with the Hobby plan or is it something related to NodeJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated by [Heroku's documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-types#dyno-sleeping), Hobby dynos do not sleep.

However, dynos of all types [are restarted frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting):

> ### Automatic dyno restarts
>
> The dyno manager restarts all your app’s dynos whenever you:
>
> - create a new [release](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases) by deploying new code
> - change your [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)
> - change your [add-ons](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/managing-add-ons)
> - run `heroku restart`
>
> Dynos are also restarted (cycled) at least once per day to help maintain the health of applications running on Heroku. Any changes to the local filesystem [will be deleted](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

I'm not entirely clear what you mean by

> it does seem to forget callback functions and `global` variables or any variables that were dynamically created and held in memory

but at least some of these things could happen due to automatic dyno restarts. Certainly anything that only exists in memory will be lost.

You could manually restart your dynos using `heroku ps:restart` and see if that replicates the behaviour you are seeing. You may need to adjust your code to survive being restarted.

Comment: I know about the automatic restarts (well they are honestly more manual ones, but whatever). What I meant was in terms of `globals`, example: I have a global counter (stored in the `global` scope) which starts at 1 (if it does not exists, aka the app just started up) and resets on 100 back to 1. So say if it stops at 5 and there is no activity on the server for some time, next time when it is suppose to increase it goes back to 1. In terms of `callbacks`, I store references to functions for later use, but just like with the counter, no activity for some time = they stop existing.

Comment: @VladislavAchramovic, if you read the documentation I quoted you'll see that there _are_ actual automatic restarts. Each dyno restarts at least once per day. Please edit your question and add the relevant code there if you want advice about it. We can't help with code we can't see. But it sounds to me like like a restart could cause exactly what you describe in your comment. If your state only exists in memory it will be lost on restart. Consider persisting it somewhere, e.g. in one of the many [data stores that Heroku supports](https://elements.heroku.com/addons).